# Use Mina JAR dependencies instead of bundles?

Tags: java, maven, apache-mina

Mina seems to be deploying their artifacts as `*.bundle` files these days, which, at the very least, is annoying and at best downright evil.

If I depend on Mina in Maven like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>${mina.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${mina.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>${mina.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

...then I get the following error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-integration-ognl:bundle:2.0.4
- Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-core:bundle:2.0.4
- Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-integration-beans:bundle:2.0.4
```

I'm not sure why it's still looking for `*.bundle` files instead of `*.jar` files. Why is it not looking for and finding the JAR files?

This is especially frustrating because I have projects which depend on this project and they all fail without the Mina JARs. Whatever happened to good-old Java JARs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First i have found out that using only the core it works without any problem, but if you start to use mina-integration-bean or mina-integration-jmx you will get the problem. Furthermore i have found the [following issue in the JIRA tracker of Mina project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-806) which exactly states your problem.

On the other hand you can exclude those bundle dependencies in maven like this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
      <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
      <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
      <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
      <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
          <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```